# how to return createdatroute location?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm attempting to create a record like so:

```
[Route("", Name = "CreateAccount")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateAccount([FromBody] JObject account)
{

    var response = await _accountService.Create(account);

    return CreatedAtRoute(
        routeName: "GetAccount",????);
}
```

The creation of the record succeeds; however. I'm not sure how to return a `CreatedAtRoute` object?

This is my GET controller method:

```
[Route("", Name = "GetAccount")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAccount()
{
    var query = Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.Split('/')[2];
    var response = _accountService.Get(query);

    if (!response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var readAsAsync = response.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
    if (readAsAsync == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var result = await readAsAsync;
    return Ok(result);
}
```

as you can see the controller does not accept any parameters, rather we get the parameters from `Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery`

**After creating a record, how do we return a valid `CreatedAtRoute` result?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can try is to pass route values as an object. The framework should convert them (route values) to query string.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("", Name = "CreateAccount")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateAccount([FromBody] JObject account) {

    var response = await _accountService.Create(account);

    var model = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyModel>();

    return CreatedAtRoute(
        routeName: "GetAccount", 
        routeValues: new { id = model.Id, name = model.Name }, // can include other properties
        content: model);
}
```

That should set the location header in the 201 response with something like

```
LOCATION: http://localhost/api/accounts?id=5&name=JDoe
```

Comment: I can confirm it does. Thanks. simply passing `model.id` not in an object won't put them in as query params